# Query transactions don't get registered in HyperLedger Fabric's BlockChain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I have been following these [instructions](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devnet-setup.md) to set up a network of validating peers using HyperLedger's BlockChain.

I was sending query transactions and I saw that query transactions don't appear in the BlockChain, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query transactions are locally served, therefore query transactions are only executed by one VP, and it is not broadcasted to the other peers (like deploy and invoke transactions). As they are not shared among peers, the query transactions do not go through consensus.

Query transactions retrieve the values from a local ledger. For this reason, queries need to be done to a trusted peer.